# cap deploy not running migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3.2.1 with Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.4 and for some reason I'm unable to run migrations.

I tried running `cap staging deploy` (deploys but doesn't run migrations), `cap staging deploy:migrate` (does nothing), `cap staging deploy:migrations` (don't know how to build task).

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
    gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end
```

Capfile:

```
set :deploy_config_path, 'config/capistrano/deploy.rb'
set :stage_config_path, 'config/capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rvm'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short trip to capistrano-rails github solved the problem. I was missing `db` role on my webservers...

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` to your Capfile

Answer (score 1):

Running "cap deploy:migrations" is equivalent to running "cap deploy" && subsequently "cap deploy:migrate" in one command.

To view the description for deploy:migrations, just use the -e option:

cap -e deploy:migrations

will give you this output:

```
cap deploy:migrations

Deploy and run pending migrations. This will work similarly to the 'deploy' task, but will also run any pending migrations (via the 'deploy:migrate' task) prior to updating the symlink. Note that the update in this case it is not atomic, and transactions are not used, because migrations are not guaranteed to be reversible.
```